# Проблемы с кодировкой кириллицы beautifulsoup в vs code

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Я только начинаю и не могу понять почему выводится это: "Р“Р»Р°РІРЅР°СЏ СЃС‚СЂР°РЅРёС†Р° Р±Р»РѕРіР°", а должно это "Главная страница блога"

вот код на питонe:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("index.html") as file:
   src=file.read()

soup=BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

title=soup.title
print(title)
```

Вот сам index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Главная страница блога</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все было очень просто:

```
with open("index.html", encoding='utf-8') as file:
```